# jQuery is not defined and $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of coding errors when "Inspecting Element" on my website. I feel like they need to be fixed and I am trying to figure it out on my own.. but I need some help now.

```
The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.
Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

My website is located at http://www.kiliwarriorexpeditions.com/

Ive been trying to read up on these errors but having a hard time to link it to my code here.. that I am not the best at figuring out.

If anybody is able to help me that would be appreciated, if not Happy New Years 2016 to you all and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main page, line number `#11`:

```
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script-->
```

You have commented this out. Uncomment it or add the jQuery from the CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also have another jQuery loaded in the end. Either move the other scripts after loading `jquery.js` or load the jQuery as first script that gets loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing help :)